# Empty swapfile after using dd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, swap, swap-file

According to many tutorials available on the internet (like for example this one https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04 ), to generate a swapfile, i need to use a following command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=4
```

However, for some reason, while that file should have 4GB of size, it has 0

```
root@vps:~# ls -sh /swapfile
0 /swapfile
```

I feel kind of helplessness because i'm not so-good superuser nor any of these tutorials provides a solution on how to deal with that. I'm also not able to find anything about that on the internet.

Comment: The tutorial you linked to seems complicated except for the Faster Way which says to use the `fallocate` program which is provided by the *libextunix-ocaml* package in Ubuntu 14.04. You can create a 4 GB swap file using: `sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile`

Comment: ok, officially, i'm an idiot that i didn't scrolled down to see that section. It's not a direct answer to my question so it should't be posted as an answer (or should it?) but i'm gonna use `fallocate`  so here is your comment up-vote :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you linked to seems complicated except for the Faster Way which says to use the `fallocate` program which is provided by the *libextunix-ocaml* package in Ubuntu 14.04. You can create a 4 GB swap file using: `sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile`